# Enclosing the content of object in double quotes in VBA

Tags: json, vba

It probably sounds simple, but I can not find a way out.
I'm trying to create a more or less dynamic json and I need to convert the content of object to a string between double quotes. Something like that  :
`""" + object + """` gives the following result `"object"` and the expected result would be `"content of object"`.

Here is my code, will probably be more clear, about what it's about.

```
Dim jsTest As String
jsTest = """ + CStr(Msg.Subject) + """ + """ + CStr(Msg.Body) + """
```

`Msg.Subject` and `Msg.Body` are objects from Email. I can do that this way(with single quotes):

```
Dim smry, descrp, jsTest As String
smry = """summary"""
descrp = """description"""
jsTest = "{" + smry + ":" + "'" + CStr(Msg.Subject) + "'" + "," + descrp + ":" + "'" + CStr(Msg.Body) + "'" + "}"
```

but then I get content of object as String with single quotes and I cant put it in my JSON like so:

```
{"summary": 'Release 18.20 Produktion', "description": 'Guten Tag Sie erhalten diese Terminanfrage'}
```

How can I get result like (**Note** double quotes):

```
{"summary": "Release 18.20 Produktion", "description": "Guten Tag Sie erhalten diese Terminanfrage"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you replace this:

```
jsTest = "{" + smry + ":" + "'" + CStr(Msg.Subject) + "'"
```

with

```
jsTest = "{" + smry + ":" + """" + CStr(Msg.Subject) + """"
```

and so on, you will get your quotes.